# What is the standard pattern for releasing a python module

Tags: python, packaging

I am new to python and have been playing around with it for a while. I have written two python modules: gapbuffer and gapbuffertests. The question I have is - to release this publically for use do I just release the gapbuffer.py module file standalone or is there a Java .jar equivalent?

Thanks,
Aly

Comment: http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Setuptools](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html) is the standard packaging solution for Python. With setuptools, you can create [eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs), which are the near-equivalent of jars. If your package is open source, you can also have it listed on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) (setuptools includes support for that) so that it can be installed with a command like `pip install gapbuffer`.

Answer (score 2):

This [short guide (The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging)](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html) might be helpful as well.